# How to use multiple arguments in ANY query when is bind message supplies parameters trhowing error?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types

I have the follow query that is using one parameter that cointains a lot of valid values to validate with ANY, rigth now I need to cast the id from bigint to int and validate with integers (This is the inital error because I was trying to use IN). This query is for postgres.

Script:

```
return `
  SELECT *
  FROM users
  WHERE  id::int = ANY(?::int[])
```

Print in the console

```
  SELECT *
  FROM users

  WHERE  id::int = ANY($1::int[])
```

This the throw an error:

```
 Args: 8988,9939,7106,6019,3284,8356,5751,8192,4726,4911,9429,1892,3026,7726,10142,182,3318,3612,10835
 Error:
 error: bind message supplies 19 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1
```

In pgadmin I can run the query, but I am not sure how to manipulate the arguments.

```
SELECT *
  FROM sites
  WHERE  id::int = ANY('{ 8988,9939 }')
```

Comment: This seems to be a client program problem, but you haven't indicated what your client language is or show us any code from it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve the query I had use javascript map to transform the values in a list of parameters ($1, $2, $3 ...) instead of using a string that is reading as one parameter ($1), with the parameters list I am covering each paramenter (is working for dynamic parameters) to avoid these error: `bind message supplies 19 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1`

```
return `
  SELECT *
  FROM users
  WHERE  id::int = ANY(ARRAY[${parameters.map(() => '?::int').join()}])
```